# PYTHON (RK4 Method), IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexoutofboundsexception, runge-kutta

I am trying to code an RK4 method for my numerical analysis course. I am getting the error:

> ```
> IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
>
> File "/Users/luciusanderson/Documents/Numerical Analysis II/RungeKutta4.py", line 62, in Runge_kutta4
>     k1 = h * f(t[i],y[i])
> ```

I am confused about what this actually means. I've tried googling and the only analysis I've come to so far is that the array I'm trying to iterate the points into starts at axis `0` and the size I'm inputting is `1`... I'm not exactly sure.

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Wed Feb 21 20:02:25 2018

@author: luciusanderson
"""

#import packages needed
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np

#==================================================================
#Runge Kutta 4th Order Approx Method

def Runge_kutta4(def_fn, a, b, N, ya ):


    """
        Test the Runge Kutta 4th Order Approx method to solve
        initial value problem y'=f(t,y) with t in [a,b] and y(a) = ya.
        Step size h is computed according to input number of mesh points N
    """

    #intialization of inputs

    f = def_fn          #intakes function to method to approximate 

    h = (b-a)/N     #creates step size based on input values of a, b,N

    t = np.arange(a, b+h, h) #array intialized to hold mesh points t

    y = np.zeros((N+1,)) # array to hold RK4 approximated y values


    y[0] = ya   #intial condition 



    #step 1
    #here i am having trouble intializing t and y intial points

    t[0] = ya
    y[0] = ya




    # step 2
    # iterative method

    for i in range(1,N+1):


                               #maybe trying this below

                               # w = y[i] ?
                               # or tau = t[i]

        #step 3
        k1 = h * f(t[i],y[i])
        k2 = h * f(t[i] + (h/2.0), y[i] +(k1/2.0))
        k3 = h * f(t[i] + (h/2.0), y[i] + (k2/2.0))
        k4 = h * f(t[i] + h, y[i] + k3)

        y[i + 1] = y[i] + (k1 + 2.0*k2 + 2.0*k3 + k4)/6.0



    return (t,y)
```

Comment: Can you post how you called this function? What is the actual error stack trace that matches this revised version of the code?

Comment: You first write `t = np.arange(a, b+h, h)` then you later you overwrite the first element with `t[0] = ya`. Is this correct?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: The line `y[i + 1] = y[i] + (k1 + 2.0*k2 + 2.0*k3 + k4)/6.0` will always exceed the bound: `y` has `N + 1` elements, and when the loop reaches the last iteration with `i == N`, it assigns to `y[N + 1]` which is out of bounds.

Comment: thanks! i changed the range to   for i in range(0,N):     and it now iterates correctly thanks !

Comment: That wasn't the line in your error message though, and that's why I ask how you invoked the function and what was the actual error msg..

Comment: You should use `t = np.linspace(a,b,N+1)` as that guarantees that you get always the expected subdivision of the interval. You could even then define `h=t[1]-t[0]`.